# flutter error:Because xylophone depends on dependencies from unknown source "english_words", version solving failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My yaml file is

```
name: xylophone
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  dependencies:
    english_words: ^4.0.0
  # Use Audioplayers dependency version 0.17.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

and when I hit the [pub-get] button, it shows

> Because xylophone depends on dependencies from unknown source "english_words", version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; Because xylophone depends on dependencies from unknown source "english_words", version solving failed.)
> Process finished with exit code 1

[image]

I have searched for solutions,but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you include full pubspec.yaml

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh  thank you for noticing!I just edit my question~

Comment: Hope my post answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dependencies` from `english_words` and use like

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^4.0.0
```

Comment: omg that works for me and I can't believe I never noticed the mistake (cry.jpg) thank you very much 55555!